# Extending bounded functions to unbounded ones

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, functions

In a proof I read - which I will omit here since it does not contribute to the question - something has to be proven for a general function $h(x): IR \rightarrow IR^+$ where $h$ is a Borel function.

At the beginning, the proof was restricted to a bounded function $h(x)$.

After the the proof had been finished, it was stated that the assumption of boundedness of $h$ can easily be relaxed by $\min(n,h(x))$, where one should note that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\min(n,h(x))= h(x)$.

However, I don't manage to see why $\min(n,h(x))$ relaxes the assumption of the bounded function $h$? For me, $|\min(n,h(x))| \leq h(x)$ holds, where $h(x)$ is still bounded, so the boundedness remains?

Thanks in advance for your help! :-)

Comment: Is the idea that you apply the previous result to the bounded function $x\mapsto \textrm{min}(n,h(x))$, then take a limit as $n\to+\infty$?

Comment: Yes exactly! :-) That was the end of the proof. The end is $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \min(n,h(x)... = ...h(x)$ So it remains a bounded function and I don't get why and where the boundedness vanishes

Comment: What is $IR?\,\,$

Comment: The real numbers @zhw... Sorry for the incorrect LaTeX notation !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing what result is being proven about $h$, I can not be certain, but here is a common approach:

1. For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, Apply the previous result to the bounded function $x\mapsto \textrm{min}(n,h(x))$.
2. Consider the sequence of functions, $(\textrm{min}\{n,h(x)\})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which converges to $h(x)$. Every element of the sequence satisfies the property implied by your proof.
3. If whatever property in your proof is preserved "in the limit" then you are done. More precisely, if the set of functions satisfying your property is closed, then you are done. It should be noted that there are plenty of properties which are not preserved "in the limit" (e.g. boundedness)!

Comment: The steps 1., 2., 3. are exactly the one in the proof - so thank you! :-) 
But I don't understand where the boundedness vanishes? In your step 2., the boundedness remains? I think this question is what you explained in 3., but unfortunately, I don't really understand it

Comment: @Kimmy Right, so each element of the sequence $(\textrm{min}\{n,h(x)\})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded while $h(x)$ might not be bounded. However, *if the set of functions satisfying your property is closed*, then we can use that to show $h(x)$ also satisfies the property. In particular, (2) shows our sequence is in the set, and it converges to $h(x)$. Since $h$ is the limit of a sequence in a closed set, it must also be in that set.

Comment: @Kimmy this graph may help visualize the inequality https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cfwdscvyly

Comment: Thank you so much for your explenations @Zim ! :-) Now, it is clear to me